# C# WPF Show loading screen while socket sending and receiving data C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

I'm building a WPF application which is using socket to transfer data to and from the server. 
The problem: While sending and receiving data from the server, the screen is frozen, and I would like to add a simple loading animation so the end user will know that it's currently loading, but I don't know how

My C# socket code:

```
public static string SendRecOne(string dataToSvr)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_NAME, PORT);
        #region SendRequest
        int ByteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(dataToSvr); //How much bytes?
        byte[] ByteBuffer = new byte[1024]; //initialize byte array
        ByteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToSvr);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(ByteBuffer, 0, ByteBuffer.Length);
        #endregion
        #region Receive Response
        //byte[] responseData = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        //int bytesRead = stream.Read(responseData, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        int i;
        string ToReturn = null;
        ByteBuffer = new byte[ByteBuffer.Length];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        while (true)
        {
            if (stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                while ((i = stream.Read(ByteBuffer, 0, ByteBuffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(ByteBuffer, 0, ByteBuffer.Length);
                    if (stream.DataAvailable)
                        continue;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                ToReturn = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                return ToReturn;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

and I'm calling it after pressing a button in window which it's name is "login.xaml", and after checking the data IS ok, it closes the current windows and initializes dashboard.xaml. 
I just need to add an animation while communicating with server.

Thanks!

Comment: I would do it with an async Task Method. And while uploading show a Busy-Indicator, or ProgressIndicator. But if your complete Architecture is synchronous, it will be a little more tedious. I guess all of this runs on the UI Thread, right?

Comment: first of all you should use a thread to keep the window from freezing in gerneral

Comment: if you just want to show a loading animation you could set window.cursor = cursors.wait

Comment: I usually put code into backgroundworker which is equivalent to creating an async Task.

Comment: @jdweng Isn't async/Task considered preferable to BGW in WPF? To me, using async Task in the context of MVVM etc feels much more straight-forward. But that may be just a matter of taste.

Comment: BTW: Stephen C had them fight each other: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-1.html

Comment: async/Task is just easier to program but has a lot less features than background mode.  Too may programmers try to take the simplest method which has limited features.

Answer (score 3):

Call your `SendRecOne` method on a background thread or make it asynchronous by using the *Async overloads:

```
public static async Task<string> SendRecOne(string dataToSvr)
{
    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    string ToReturn = null;
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_NAME, PORT))
    {
        int ByteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(dataToSvr); //How much bytes?
        byte[] ByteBuffer = new byte[1024]; //initialize byte array
        ByteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToSvr);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        await stream.WriteAsync(ByteBuffer, 0, ByteBuffer.Length);

        //byte[] responseData = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        //int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(responseData, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        int i;
        ByteBuffer = new byte[ByteBuffer.Length];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        if (stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            while ((i = await stream.ReadAsync(ByteBuffer, 0, ByteBuffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                await ms.WriteAsync(ByteBuffer, 0, ByteBuffer.Length);
                if (!stream.DataAvailable)
                    break;
            }
            ToReturn = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
        progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    return ToReturn;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" />
```

The UI thread cannot both process messages and execute your code simultaneously.